# Data in request.body can't be found by request.data - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I'm writing a django application. I am trying to call my django rest framework from outside, and expecting an answer.
I use requests to send some data to a function in the DRF like this:

```
j=[i.json() for i in AttachmentType.objects.annotate(text_len=Length('terms')).filter(text_len__gt=1)]
j = json.dumps(j)
url = settings.WEBSERVICE_URL + '/api/v1/inference'
headers = {
   'Content-Disposition': f'attachment; filename={file_name}',
   'callback': 'http://localhost',
   'type':j,
   'x-api-key': settings.WEBSERVICE_API_KEY
   }
data = {
   'type':j
   }
files = {
   'file':file
}
response = requests.post(
    url,
    headers=headers,
    files=files,
    json=data,
)
```

In the DRF, i use the request object to get the data.

```
class InferenceView(APIView):
    """
    From a pdf file, extract infos and return it
    """
    permission_classes = [HasAPIKey]

    def post(self, request):
        print("REQUEST FILE",request.FILES)
        print("REQUEST DATA",request.data)
        callback = request.headers.get('callback', None)
        # check correctness of callback
        msg, ok = check_callback(callback)
        if not ok: # if not ok return bad request
            return build_json_response(msg, 400)

        # get zip file
        zip_file = request.FILES.get('file', None)  
        parsed = json.loads(request.data.get('type', None).replace("'","\""))
```

The problem is that the data in the DRF are not received correctly. Whatever I send from the requests.post is not received.
I am sending a file and a JSON together. The file somehow is received, but other data are not.
If I try to do something like

```
request.data.update({"type":j})
```

in the DRF, the JSON is correctly added to the data, so it is not a problem with the JSON I'm trying to send itself.
Another thing, request.body shows that the JSON is somehow present in the body, but request.data can't find it.
I don't want to use request.body directly because I can't understand why it is present in the body but not visible with request.data.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
response = requests.post(
    url,
    headers=headers,
    files=files,
    json=data,
)
```

replace **json=data** with **data=data**

like this:

```
response = requests.post(
    url,
    headers=headers,
    files=files,
    data=data,
)
```

Comment: Yes I've tried that but if i print request.data i still see only this: REQUEST DATA {'file': <InMemoryUploadedFile: up.zip (multipart/form-data; boundary=5a2227188d2b8ab3031a9914a1b14882)>}